# Is there another way to develop applications for mobile phones running the Windows Operating System other than Windows Dev Tools?

Tags: windows-mobile, development-environment

Is there another way to develop applications for mobile phones running the Windows Operating System for example, the HTC HD2 Mobile Phone (which runs Windows 6.5), other than Windows Dev Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. An example is J2ME if there is a Java Virtual Machine for the OS!

Comment: Hmmm. I'd have to learn Java then, and I come from C++/C#... Well, I guess I could give it a go! :) What if I just try to run existing C# .NET apps that work on my computer... You think they'll run on the phone? At all?

Comment: Look up some Java code! It looks just like C#, just the libraries are different. Desktop .NET apps will not run on the phone because it uses CompactFramework.NET which is a subset of the desktop version. However you should be able to re-compile certain code that uses compatible framework features and target the CF.NET framework instead.

Comment: So if I can find out how to use Visual Studio Express to target cf.net, then I should be able to develop my apps as i normally would with desktop apps? Hmmm... if that fails i'll go get me some java! thank you heaps

Comment: I didn't say that there definitely was a JVM for that OS, just that there are some for some phone OSes. You'd have to check that. If you are starting from scratch on an app or want to port part of your existing .NET app, I'd recommend going the Microsoft way. I've developed for Windows Mobile 6 with VS2008 Pro, and all I had to do was download the Windows Mobile 6 SDK, install it, and plug the device in via USB. Development looks and feels very similar to WinForms work (except of course the reduced feature API available).

Comment: Awesome! Well, I might see if there's a trial version available for VS2008

Comment: Well there is - Visual Studio Express. First try getting that and then getting the WinMobile SDK and installing. That should hopefully enable  you to proceed! I simply don't know if the SDK will work with the free version of VS. Good luck!